# Remove order line button

Tags: odoo-8, odoo

I try to remove line with name "Services" with this method, but no luck.

```
    @api.multi
    def remove_line(self):
         for line in self.order_line:
            if line.name == 'Services':
                self.order_line.write({
                       'line': [(3, self.product_id.id)]
                    })
```

Comment: its in sale.order in form view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
@api.multi
def remove_line(self):
    for rec in self:
        for line in rec.order_line:
            if line.name == 'Services':
                line.unlink()
```

Answer (score 1):

And if you want to do it using cammand do it like this :

```
      # update the record it self
      self.write({
                   # update the one2many field and remove the current line in for loop
                   'order_line': [(3, line.id)]
                })
```

Only one2many or many2many accept cammand line